# Manual Session in Spring MVC Not Working

Tags: session, spring-mvc, tomcat6

I am trying to set a session variable and retrieve it on a future request.  I see there are several ways to do this in Spring MVC.  I have tried several ways but none of them are working.  I went back to the simplest way (manual session manipulation) and still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class Test {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

@RequestMapping({ "/set", "/set/" })
public final ModelAndView set(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response, 
        final HttpSession session) {

    LOG.info("setting the session");
    session.setAttribute("userId", new Object());
    request.getSession(true).setAttribute("userId", new Object());

    return new ModelAndView("someView");
}

@RequestMapping({ "/get", "/get/" })
public final ModelAndView get(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response, 
        final HttpSession session) {

    final HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
    final Object userId = session.getAttribute("userId");
    final Object userId1 = session1.getAttribute("userId");
    LOG.info("and the userId is '" + userId + "' '" + userId1 + "'");

    return new ModelAndView("someView");
}
}
```

I hit my server at /set, then at /get.  I look at my logs and see:

```
setting the session
and the userId is 'null' 'null'
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but putting the following in my web.xml fixed the problem:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```